# I need the start and end date of workers joining in Excell

Tags: excel, vba

In excel sheet,row 1, I have Dates:1,2,3,4,5…………..31. ,,, in row 2 to 6 I have person names.  05 persons worked for me last month, every one worked for 10 days only (consecutive)  on different dates, I want to know the start and end of work for every person. Suppose A worked from 6th to 15th so system should return 6th in start and 15th in end date for A. I need start and end date of every person individually, any function in excel other than IF.

Comment: Can you post your excel so that it will give better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use Columns for the Date, the worker, EndDate should be a formula like this:

```
=A1 + 10
```

If you've got the dates in Date format in the first Column Excel knows to add days with "+10".

You should use an if statement if you only want the cells to populate if there's a worker in the column though.

```
=IF(B1="","", A1+10)
```

Just copy and paste the formula down Column C.

Answer (score 0):

=MAX(IF($A2:$AE2<>"",$a$1:$ae$1)) press ctrl + shift + enter 
This will give you the start date of the person in row 2.  Under the circumstance that the name is only written once in the column of the start date. Add 9 to that value to receive the end date. Copy down to the other rows to see the date of that person. 
If the name is written in each column when the person has worked this formula will return the end date. Subtract 9 to receive the start date.